# Limit points of a real function.

Tags: analysis

> Given a real number $a$ and an no empty compact set $K$, get a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the set of the limit point of $f$ in $a$ is $K$.

Can anyone give a hint to this problem? I think I should do a partitions on the real numbers, but I don't know how.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b\in K$. 
Let 
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{x-a}\sin\frac1{x-a}&\text{if }x\ne a\\0&\text{if }x=a \end{cases}$$
and
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&\text{if }g(x)\in K\\b&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Comment: To prove that it works:
I take $y\in K$. Since $K$ is compact there exist a sucession $y_n$ such that $y_n\rightarrow y $. Since $g(x)$ is surjective for each $y_n$ there exist $x_n$ with the propierty $g(x_n)=y_n$. Then $f(x_n)=g(x_n)=y_n$, this implies that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)=y$. Then each $y\in K$ is a limit point of $f$. 
The other part is rather easier, if $x\not\in K$ then $f(x)=b$ then there is no others limit points.

Is this right?